# Show text when clicking image using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a food menu website with images for each food entry. They are actually checkbox's labeled as images. When I click on any of the menu images, it displays a custom checkbox I have coded using CSS.

In addition to this, I would like to have text displayed further down on my page which basically specify what food items have been checked. So if I choose corn, I will want the word "CORN" to display in another section of my html page.

Also, the text should hide if the item is then unchecked.

I would preferably like to do this using CSS alone, but if not I can use some javascript.

Here is what I have. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label"><img src="images\cucumber.png"></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label"><img src="images\chickpea.png"></label>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label"><img src="images\corn.png"></label>
```

**CSS Code**

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
                        position:absolute; z-index:-1000; left:-1000px; overflow:        hidden; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height:1px; width:1px; margin:-1px; padding:0; border:0;
                    }

                    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
                        padding-left:40px;
                        height:45px; 
                        display:inline-block;
                        line-height:45px;
                        background-repeat:no-repeat;
                        background-position: 0 0;
                        font-size:5px;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                        cursor:pointer;
                        margin-bottom:165px

                    }

                    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
                        background-position: 0 -45px;
                    }
                    label.css-label {
            background-image:url(http://localhost/images/csscheckbox_7cdb0340e1b30df1c5ec1b06aac0dca1.png);
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
```

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0vv38chx/)

Comment: You have to use JavaScript for this. CSS doesn't handle logic, only presentation, and remembering which images were clicked falls squarely under logic.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely a Javascript thing. Your doing some calculation and manipulating the DOM.

Comment: Now, if you had a `div` right after the checkbox and hid it until checked, that would work in CSS: `input[type=checkbox]:checked+.myDiv { visibility: visible; }`

Comment: Doing this in CSS will be very very difficult to maintain. This is simple to do in JQuery.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are saying about CSS not being a realistic option. Can someone provide some code that may help make this happen with javascript or jquery in my specific circumstance? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

There is not such a function as onClick in CSS, you could use the :hover or :active tag. ( :active is the closest you can get )

You could also use the onClick="" attribute inside of the image tag to toggle some javascript function.